# Does it improve security to remove root@% from local mysql container?

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a mysql docker container, when the volume is created on boot, the following initial script is called which creates a database, gives a user access to that database and deletes the root user with '%' access:

```
define DDL <<-sql
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${DATABASE}\`;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON \`${DATABASE}\`.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%';
    DELETE FROM mysql.user WHERE User='root' AND Host NOT IN ('localhost', '127.0.0.1', '::1');
sql
```

And I am wondering, why root user with host `%` are deleted. Does it add security? Do I even need any security constraints for a local container? I am sitting behind a normal router at my home office.

Would there be any problem with leaving the root user? Or granting my user all privileges?

```
define DDL <<-sql
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS \`${DATABASE}\`;
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '$MYSQL_USER'@'%';
sql
```

Or do I need to restrict the privileges, to protect against the scenario that a stranger somehow finds a way to login into my local docker container?

Comment: @schroeder for the question about `%` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/11634124 . I just have the general question, can people login from outside to the container. The initial script happens when the container is booted. I thought maybe they remove root@% so that one can only login from localhost and not from another place. Why do you thinl I misunderstand the script?

Comment: ... right ... so it is not "`%` permissions" as I was trying to say. `%` is a host. "can people login from outside to the container" -- outsideness is determined by the network, which I have said you have not discussed.

Comment: Your edits do make a lot more clear, and would then make this a pure MySQL question and not a Docker question.

Comment: Wow, first question in my life on StackExchange that was reopend. Thanks!

Comment: Your right in that the difference between an ordinary database user and a root database user inside a container if fairly small (like root can `shutdown` and ordinary users can't) and in the scheme of risk management, there's not much difference.